# Spring/Hibernate adding a shutdown hook running prior to closing the EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, websphere

When I close down my server, I have jobs that are populating downloading and populating data that I would like to allow to finish gracefully.

I tried to add a Runtime.getRuntime().addShutDownHook() but this seems to run after the Entitymanager is already closed, as exception starts pouring in before that gets ran.

Then I tried to add it to implement a ServletContextListener and

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent)
```

which ran before the shutdown hook but still after the entitymanager had already closed.

Is there a way to run some logic prior to the entitymanager shutting down?

I am injecting the entitymanager using

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

The EntitymanagerFactory is created using

```
@Configuration 

@Bean(name= PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
.... createEntityManagerFactory()
```

How can I properly listen to when the entitymanager gets shut down, so I can allow pending work to complete first?

I am using Spring, Hibernate, JPA on Java EE with a web module.

The resulting exception is this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
        org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:388)
        org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:342)
        org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
        sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:541)
        com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:285)
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:252)
        com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.getDelegate(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `EntityManagerFactory` that get's closed when the Spring application context is destroyed.

According to your logged exception, the main running thread has detected the application destroy event and the [Spring shutdownHook](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook--) propagates the destroy event to all registered beans, `EntityManagerFactory` included.

You probably have a batch job that has some worker threads, that don't listen to the application destroy event and therefore they continue to execute, therefore trying to create an `EntityManager` using a closed `EntityManagerFactory`.

Because the application context is destroyed, it's not just the `EntityManagerFactory` that is closed, but the `TransactionManager` and the `DataSource` as well. That's why there's not much you can do about it, other than discarding your current running batch jobs and simply unacknowledge the 
unfinished items.

The solution is to use a persisted message queue for recording any pending work. If the server is closed, the currently processing messages shouldn't be acknowledged and so they get a chance to be reprocessed the next time you start your server.